# $A.getCallback function in setTimeout runs 3 times in a row

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am doing polling in my Lightning Component using `setTimeout` and `$A.getCallback` but the **callback is called 3 times in a row** at the next tick.

Controller.js:

```
  // Fired one time at component creation
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.mainAction(component);
  }
```

Helper.js:

```
mainAction: function(component) {
    const recordId    = component.get("v.recordId");
    const sObjectName = component.get('v.sObjectName');
    const action      = component.get("c.doAction");

    action.setParams({
      sObjectName: sObjectName,
      recordId: recordId
    });

    action.setCallback(this, response => {

      const state = response.getState();

      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        const response = response.getReturnValue();
        console.log('sobj found:', response);
        // do stuff
      } else { // do stuff }

      setTimeout($A.getCallback(() => this.mainAction(component)), 5000);
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

[image: 3 times in a row]

The required flow is:

1. DoInit (init handler)
2. Fetching data
3. Fetching data

   .

   .

   n. Same action as `n-1`

Comment: Shouldn't this line `() => this.mainAction(component)` be `() => { this.mainAction(component);}` (I could easily be wrong - I don't know much about ES6 Syntax)

Comment: Is the "this" in your $A.getCallback definitely the helper object still? I usually assign this to some variable in the outer scope to ensure I'm still using what I want

Comment: ... and according to [Compatibility section of the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) `=>` is not supported in e.g. IE11. Safer to use the better known `function` syntax.

Comment: Indeed it defines the helper, but we are in a lambda function (@Caspar) , the context is preserved (@MatthGoldspink).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

"An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used."

Comment: @MattGoldspink this syntax does not create a new this scope, so `this` is fine

Comment: @KeithC in my case, I do not take care of IE11.

Comment: Can you verify that this problem is/is not occuring using ES5 syntax?

Comment: @CasparHarmer It still happens

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by sending the data in the recursion instead of getting the information from `component`:

Controller.js:

```
  // Fired one time at component creation
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    const recordId    = component.get("v.recordId");
    const sObjectName = component.get('v.sObjectName');
    helper.mainAction(component, recordId, sObjectName);
  }
```

Helper.js:

```
mainAction: function(component, recordId, sObjectName) {
    const action      = component.get("c.doAction");

    action.setParams({
      sObjectName: sObjectName,
      recordId: recordId
    });

    action.setCallback(this, response => {

      const state = response.getState();

      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        const response = response.getReturnValue();
        console.log('sobj found:', response);
        // do stuff
      } else { // do stuff }

      setTimeout($A.getCallback(() => this.mainAction(component, recordId, sObjectName)), 5000);
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: Good to know. I was able to make the issue go away by putting setTimeout  as the first statement in the setCallback function.

Comment: Although I had a different issue. Probably caused by something similar though - component validity, storing of actions etc

Comment: Another issue popping from this behaviour is when the polling is fired and you browse to another record page WHERE THE LIGHTNING COMPONENT IS NOT PRESENT, this JS behaviour is still working in back (cf. browser developer console network): Salesforce does not unmount/delete the component...